# Problema ao utilizar parágrafos em arquivo JSON

Tags: javascript, json

Estou criando uma aplicação web a qual utiliza arquivos JSON para salvar o conteúdo do site.

Nesses arquivos são salvos pequenos fragmentos de texto contendo parágrafos. Quando eu tento separar o parágrafo utilizando um `\n\` ou `\n` ou `\r\` ou `\r`, eu não tenho a quebra de linha e se usar o `\n\` ou `\r\` o arquivo JSON não é carregado.

Qual a forma correta para colocar quebras de linha para separar parágrafos em arquivos JSON?

Já testei códigos HTML como `<p>` ou um `<br/>` mas isso não funcionaria bem em alerts.

Arquivo JSON:

```
{
  "pt":{
    "title":"Quem é Ohm Reaction",
    "article":"hadouken!\\n asda"
    }
}
```

Comment: Este parece ser um problema de formatação do código na hora de exibi-lo ao invés de um problema com o formato JSON. Como é o código que você usa para exibi-lo?

Comment: quando eu utilizava \\n ele trazia o \n como se fosse parte do texto, o \n ele realmente pula pra próxima linha... meu erro era que quando eu inseria o json na div ele mostrava o espaço mas para o HTML \n é representado como no máximo um espaço entre caracteres... minha solução vai ser converter na entrada

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta um `\n` simples na string final do json.

```
>>> var pessoa = { nome: 'James Bond', apresentacao: 'Meu nome é Bond...\n\nJames Bond.' };  
>>> console.log(pessoa.apresentacao);
Menu nome é Bond...

James Bond.
```

Comment: Só gostaria de chamar à atenção o fato de que o seu exemplo não é [JSON](http://www.json.org/json-pt.html), é simplesmente um objeto JavaScript comum. JSON não aceita aspas simples, nem permite que os nomes dos atributos sejam expressos sem aspas. A confusão é comum, dada a similaridade entre **o formato** JSON e o **literal para objetos** de JavaScript. O primeiro se inspirou no segundo, e de fato você pode fazer `eval` em um JSON e o resultado sempre será um objeto válido. A recíproca não é verdadeira (nem todo literal para objeto JS será considerado JSON válido).

Answer (score 7):

O uso de barras duplas (`\\n`, `\\r` etc) em geral somente é necessário quando se está lidando com uma string representando outra string:

```
var texto1 = "foo\nbar";    // foo
                            // bar
var texto2 = "'foo\nbar'";  // 'foo
                            // bar'
var texto3 = "'foo\\nbar'"; // 'foo\nbar'
```

Essa é a mesma razão pela qual linguagens sem um literal para expressões regulares (como Java) - ou funções/construtores que criam uma regex a partir de uma string - precisam das barras duplas:

```
var regex1 = /(.)\1/;              // Regex: (.)\1
                                   // Valida "xx": sim
var regex2 = new RegExp("(.)\1");  // Regex: (.) 
                                   // Valida "xx": não
var regex3 = new RegExp("(.)\\1"); // Regex: (.)\1
                                   // Valida "xx": sim
```

No caso de um JSON contido em uma string, portanto, ela é necessária:

```
var json1 = '{ "texto":"foo\nbar" }';  // { "texto":"foo
                                       // bar" }
var json2 = '{ "texto":"foo\\nbar" }'; // { "texto":"foo\nbar" }
```

Mas se esse JSON foi lido de um arquivo, não, pois a barra invertida será incluída diretamente na string (e não interpretada de qualquer forma como um caractere de escape).

Sei que isso não responde diretamente sua pergunta (uma vez que já foi determinado nos comentários que seu problema era no momento de exibir o texto usando HTML), mas espero que ajude a ilustrar por que em algumas situações se usa `\n` e outras `\\n`: no primeiro você está "escapando" o `n`, no outro você está escapando a própria `\` (e mantendo o `n` intacto).

Comment: obrigado pelas informações, todo conhecimento é bem vindo.

Answer (score 1):

Supondo que você está usando aspas no seu arquivo JSON, use `\\n` para quebra de linha.

O formato JSON exige que certos caracteres especiais, como a quebra de linha, sejam "escapados" usando `\`. Portanto, para produzir a string `\n`, você deve escapar a barra `\` usando outra barra antes.

Comment: Meu arquivo JSON:`{"pt":{"title":"Quem é Ohm Reaction","article":"hadouken!\\n asda"}}` mesmo assim o \\n não resolve. ele é chamado e mostrado na tela como "hadouken!\n asda"

Comment: Eu não consigo fazer quebra de linha também, alguém tem uma solução? Tentei com duas barras também, mas não foi.

Answer (score -4):

Coloque \n onde quer quebrar a linha, depois use um slice para fatiar essas partes e assim você terá vários elementos no seu array e poderá em seguida quebrar em linhas.